# Modify Excel Pivot Table with Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: excel

I know it is possible to modify the rows, columns and values of a pivot table with VBA. However, is it possible to modify the views of an excel pivot table with keyboard stroke alone (assume the mouse cannot be used)?

Answer (score 1):

This sample hide a column.
In the workbook add:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{F12}", "Macro1"
End Sub
```

in a module add:

```
Sub Macro1()
    If Not Application.Intersect(Selection, Range("E10:F15")) Is Nothing Then
        If ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("a").Orientation = xlHidden Then
            With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("a")
                .Orientation = xlRowField
                .Position = 1
            End With
        Else
            ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("a").Orientation = xlHidden
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In the sample when you press F12 tyhe code hide/show the column filed "a", ONLY if you are inside the pivot (selection). If you want always remove the first if.